# How do WordPress restore trashed posts to previous status?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm am creating a simple administration system for one of my sites, and now I am creating a blog inspired by WordPress' posts system.

In my blog you can save it as either a draft or a published version.
And now I want to create a way, so when you delete a blog, it will change to "trashed" in the database. And when you restore it, it will be restored as the same type again, just like WordPress.

But how do WordPress restore it's trashed posts, to the original post_status? I have looked at the WordPress database, but I couldn't figure out, how it does it, cause the original post_status is replaced with "trash" when it is trashed and is not stored any other place in the table.

So how does it "remember" it's original post_status? Hope you understand what I'm asking :D

Sorry for not being a code-related question, but I couldn't find any answer any other places.

- Thanks

Comment: `trash` is post status not a post type. you can do it easily just by adding a column to your posts table named post_status . so then you can organize your posts by their status . 
like , `draft` , `publish` , `trash` and so on ....

Comment: It stores the previous status. Does not matter where. You are implementing a new system, you choose where to store it.

Comment: I have searched it the database, and it does not store the previous status

Answer (score 1):

To be short:

The previous post-status of a WordPress post, is stored in the wp_postmeta table.
In that table, the time for when the post were trashed, also are stored.

If you then restore the post, the rows of containing data for that specific post, are removed.

That should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic stuff to be frank. You should look at the wp_posts table and see the difference between a trashed and a published post ( and possibly, others too). Wordpress does this  by changing the post_status column for that particular row of data. This way it knows the current status of the post concerned.

It might not be related to the answer but for those who are looking for answer to this question, should consider looking at the data source, i.e. the database of any system you are trying to learn... Be it Wordpress or Moodle.

Comment: But when the column is changed to "trash" how does it know what the previous status was?

Comment: @Kristiansen what made you think that it does?

Comment: Because if you click on restore in WordPress it restores to the previous status.

Answer (score 0):

All the posts, pages, and cpts are stored in `{table_prefix}_posts`in the database.

The posts, pages, or cpts which are trashed have the `post_status` as `trash` in some cases the permalink is also changed to `__trashed`

```
e.g; http://example.com/sample-page__trashed
```

To restore the post page, change the `post_status` back to `published` and remove `__trashed` from the permalink if  it exists.

I recently fixed the issue on the site which was using the 'Frontend User Pro' plugin and the login page and reset password page was trashed. The site was not working and I fixed it using the above method.